# nodejs async await all data in one variable

Tags: node.js

I want to check If a Domain is on spam list.

```
const dnsbl = require('dnsbl');
 
const spam1 = await dnsbl.lookup('127.0.0.2', 'zen.spamhaus.org');

 
const spam2 = await dnsbl.lookup('127.0.0.2', 'zen.spamhaus.org', {includeTxt: true});

const spam3 = ...
```

I want to check 30 Spamsite. Do I have to make now 30 variables like spam4, spam5, spam6? Or is there a more efficient way to do it?

And how do I save all the results that are found in a variable?

Comment: you can't use ```async/await``` in global scope (till this time), you have to use simple promise.  ```dnsbl.lookup('x.x.x.x', 'example.com').then((args)=>)```

Comment: and Use ```promise.all``` to make it concurrent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following code executes all 30 methods in parallel, and returns you (only if all the 30 promises executed successfuly) the 30 results.

```
const dnsbl = require('dnsbl');

(async () => {
    const promiseArr = [
        dnsbl.lookup('127.0.0.2', 'zen.spamhaus.org'),
        dnsbl.lookup('127.0.0.2', 'zen.spamhaus.org'),
        dnsbl.lookup('127.0.0.2', 'zen.spamhaus.org'),
        dnsbl.lookup('127.0.0.2', 'zen.spamhaus.org'),
        ...,
        ...,
    ];
    let results;

    try {
        results = await Promise.all(promiseArr);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(e);
    }
})();
```

Comment: Thank you! Very helpful. can you answer one last question for me? If a Blacklist/Spam site is found, then I want to show on which Spamlist-server.

Comment: I editet my question look about your comment^^

Comment: @servermanager018 This is more specific library question. I don't really know this library, maybe try to re-write your question without being too specific with the library if possible?

Comment: All Good, i have to use batch instead of lookup. Thank you very much